# Determine when $(3^x - y^3)(x^3 - 3^y)$ is a perfect square

Tags: elementary-number-theory, perfect-squares

> Determine all integers $x,y$ such that $f:=(3^x-y^3)(x^3-3^y)$ is a perfect square.

What I have thought: the problem seems a bit hard to begin with. I first tried the situation that $\gcd(x,3)=\gcd(y,3)=1$ and was stuck. It would help a lot if we can make some progress in $\gcd(3^x-y^3,x^3-3^y)$, but I failed. However, if you just expand it, it still seems useless.

Any idea which makes progress is welcomed.

Comment: x=y lol.........

Comment: [Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25280597/) I wrote a program to find all $(x,y)\in[0,1000]^2$, and got `[[0, 1], [1, 0], [3, 3], [6, 9], [9, 6], [9, 27], [12, 81], [15, 243], [18, 729], [27, 9], [81, 12], [243, 15], [729, 18]]`.  From this, it seems like looking at $(3k,3^k)$ and $(3^k,3k)$ may be useful.  Unfortunately, showing all solutions are of this form is likely more difficult.

Comment: @SakethMalyala, this would lead to $f(x,y) = -n^2$, which is almost a perfect square, but alas not quite

Comment: @Mark, strangely enough, all the values are also the solutions to $f(x,y) = 0$.

Comment: @GJon, where did you find this problem? $\LaTeX$ tip, `\gcd` gives a better look cf. $\gcd$ and $gcd$

Comment: @mdave16 One of my classmates asked me.

Comment: The expression can only be equal to one of $\{0,2,4,6,7\}$ modulo $8$, so it can only be a square when it's divisible by $8$ (and hence by $16$).